# How can I filter date-time columns by dates in Propel 1.6?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, propel

I would like to filter results as in

```
$searchDate = "2013-03-01";

$query->usePublicationQuery()
            ->filterByPublishedAt($searchDate)
            ->endUse();
```

However, the problem is, that the values in this column contain also the time, i.e. they're actually timestamps (e.g. "2013-03-01 08:27:12") and I'm not allowed to change that in the schema. So how can I possibly match the pure date ignoring the time? The above query only matches entries with the time 2013-03-01 00:00:00. But I want all entries with 2013-03-01 as date, regardless of the time.

Comment: I think you choose the best solution.

Comment: Seems to be a self-answering question then. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Then you can remove the solution from your question, post it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: Just copied the solution as answer. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've figured out this solution and it works:

```
->filterByPublishedAt(array("min" => $searchDate." 00:00:00", "max" => $searchDate." 23:59:59"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using instances of Criteria and don't want to/cannot switch to the "new way" of writing queries: simply use Criteria::CUSTOM instead of Criteria::LIKE.

E.g.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(SomePeer::CREATED_AT, $date.'%', Criteria::LIKE);
```

becomes

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(SomePeer::CREATED_AT, SomePeer::CREATED_AT.' LIKE "'.$date.'%"',Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

That way, Propel won't try to convert it to a DateTime object.