# Propel filter all rows that have today's date as a timestamp in mysql database

Tags: php, propel

How can I filter results only for current day (today) using propel:

```
$checkIfMaxNrOfPointsTransactionsForToday = PointsTransactionsQuery::create()                  
            ->filterByTimeCreated(array('max' => 'today'))              
            ->filterByUserId($this->userId)
            ->count();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337355/how-can-i-filter-date-time-columns-by-dates-in-propel-1-6/15358057#15358057) is an answer i found usefull. Just put min and max within the current date.